# How to be notified if twitter url length changes

Tags: twitter

Twitter shortens (or lengthens) all URL’s you input in your tweets using Twitter's link service (http://t.co).  A few years ago all links were converted to 20 characters, but recently, I found out it is now 23 characters. Since we tweet via an API, we need to calculate these characters ourselves. Do you have any idea how I can stay updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you [read the developer docs](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/help/configuration) you will see that there is an API call for just this purpose.

You need to GET `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/help/configuration.json` (remember to make an OAuth signed call) and you'll get back...

```
"short_url_length": 23,
"short_url_length_https": 23
```

Along with a bunch of other data about image sizes, limits, reserved names, file sizes, etc.

Comment: This API is retired as of June 29th, 2021.